# Tablero ajedrez en java

Tags: java, array

Me han pedido crear un tablero de ajedrez y ya, todo bien, el problema surge cuando le quiero dar color a las casillas y no entiendo el por qué.
El código mas abajo me crea el tablero, el problema está aquí:

```
        if((y+x+1)%2==0){
            Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }else{
            Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
```

Me da el siguiente error

```
prueba.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

            Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                                  ^
symbol:   method setBackground(Color)
 location: class String
   prueba.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                    Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                                                  ^
   symbol:   method setBackground(Color)
   location: class String
   2 errors
```

La verdad no entiendo, he visto otros códigos para crear un tablero, pero, sinceramente no quisiera copiar y pegar, quisiera entender el código que he creado, para abordar este problema.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;


import javax.swing.*;

public class prueba {

public static JPanel TableroAjedrez() {
    JPanel PanelTableroAjedrez = new JPanel();
    String[][] Casillas = new String[8][8];
    for(int y=0; y < Casillas.length; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x < Casillas[y].length; x++) {
            PanelTableroAjedrez.add(new JButton(Casillas[y][x]));
            if((y+x+1)%2==0){
                Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }else{
                Casillas[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }

    PanelTableroAjedrez.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));


    return PanelTableroAjedrez;
}       






public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame Ventana = new JFrame("Tablero de Ajedrez");
    Ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    Ventana.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    Ventana.add(TableroAjedrez());

    Ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Ventana.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    Ventana.pack();
    Ventana.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: La variable Casillas (que deberia ser casillas) son Strings. Los Strings no tienen ningún método `setBackground` por eso el error. Por cierto el 'Hellos' me ha matado .....

Comment: thx por la aclaracion, no sabia eso de los strings. Como que el hellos te ha matado xDD

Comment: Es Ellos, no Hellos.

Comment: na men xD, lo que pasa es que en mi instituto nos saludamos de esta forma: holas como estan, tons algunos lo enredamos al ingles hellos como estan, hello es lo normal y le ponemos S al final hellos. Se me olvido que no estaba en la escuela, suerte a todos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que el arreglo llamado **Casillas** es de tipo **String[][]** es decir que:

```
Casillas[y][x]
```

Es una variable de tipo **String** y la clase **String** no tiene un metodo llamado **setBackground**.

Lo que entiendo que quieres es implementar el tablero de ajedres de manera que cada casilla sea un **JButton**. Un **JButton** si tiene el metodo **setBackground**.

Por tanto te suguiero que sustituyas tu for por el siguiente:

```
for(int x=0; x < Casillas[y].length; x++) {
    // en lugar de hacer el add a new JButton 
    // primero declaras una variable asignandole lo que ya pasabas
    // en el metodo add
    final JButton jButton = new JButton(Casillas[y][x]);
    PanelTableroAjedrez.add(jButton);
    if((y+x+1)%2==0){
        // al botón le pones el color negro como en tu condición
        jButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
        // o le pones el color blanco aquí tu logica es practicamente la misma
        jButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido claro.
Quedo atento a cualquier comentario

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tons el problema era ese. Thx por la aclaracion muy detallada